# PHP, MYSQL count yearly output

Tags: mysql, sql

My problem is I have a table like this:

```
recordID  patientID    date       treatment     
   1         1      2016-02-12  Dental Hygiene   
   2         2      2016-03-30  Exam & Cleanings   
   3         2      2016-02-12  Flouride Treatment    
   4         1      2016-05-17  Exam & Cleanings     
   5         3      2016-06-22  Flouride Treatment
   6         3      2016-02-01  Flouride Treatment
   7         3      2017-02-29  Teeth Whitening
   8         4      2017-10-12  Bridges
   9         3      2017-11-02  Teeth Whitening
   10        2      2018-02-12  Bridges
   11        4      2018-08-20  Compsite Fillings
   12        1      2018-10-05  Bridges
   13        2      2018-12-12  Teeth Whitening
```

So somehow I want to get data like this:

```
YEAR: 2016
treatment: Dental Hygiene
count: 1
treatment: Exam & Cleanings
count: 2
treatment: Flouride Treatment
count: 3

YEAR: 2017
treatment: Bridges
count: 1
treatment: Teeth Whitening
count: 2

YEAR: 2018
treatment: Compsite Fillings
count: 1
treatment: Teeth Whitening
count: 1
treatment: Bridges
count: 2
```

Is it possible to get this result from a query?

I have this query so far. but the problem is the YEAR it's repeatedly printed the same year.

```
SELECT YEAR(date), treatment, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM patient_records
GROUP BY YEAR(date), treatment
```

Comment: You seem to want a result set that has a single column with different types (or are those strings, I'm not sure).  In any case, this is not a very SQL way to structure data.  Such transformations are usually done at the application layer.

Comment: do I need to use php to get that result?

Comment: that would be a suitable tool, if you are already using it.

Comment: yes, I'm using it but I do not know how to start. what do I use if statement, for loop, array? sry I'm new to php